# How switch first column to last

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with columns as below:

```
1|occlitn.usrelevan@gmail.com|||gmail.com|Occlitnfnelevan|Occlitnlnelevan|Occlitnfnelevan Occlitnlnelevan||||||||||1||||1|2019-04-19 11:40:17|
249108103169|ocusr_onetwo@demopersistent.com|||demopersistent.com|OCFNONETWO|OCLNONETWO|OCFNONETWO OCLNONETWO|A09012|Sales Manager|Pune|UU 5C46 3||Telecom & Media|FY11_Telecom_DU3|Telecom & Media-ToBeAllocated|Role-Twelve|1|+91-20-67000000|9000000012||1|2019-04-19 11:40:17|
```

There are total 23 pipe-delimiters and 24 columns
I want to switch the first column to last as below:

```
occlitn.usrelevan@gmail.com|||gmail.com|Occlitnfnelevan|Occlitnlnelevan|Occlitnfnelevan Occlitnlnelevan||||||||||1||||1|2019-04-19 11:40:17|1|
ocusr_onetwo@demopersistent.com|||demopersistent.com|OCFNONETWO|OCLNONETWO|OCFNONETWO OCLNONETWO|A09012|Sales Manager|Pune|UU 5C46 3||Telecom & Media|FY11_Telecom_DU3|Telecom & Media-ToBeAllocated|Role-Twelve|1|+91-20-67000000|9000000012||1|2019-04-19 11:40:17|249108103169|
```

i Tried below reg-ex in notepad++ after ctrl+h but it is not working correctly:

```
(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|
\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9|\10|\11|\12|\13|\14|\15|\16|\17|\18|\19|\20|\21|\22|\23|\24|\1|
```

Require pointers on an easy way to move the first column to last from notepad++ as using excel is troublesome as it changes the data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^|]+\|)(.+$)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  ([^|]+\|) # group 1, 1 or more non pipe and a pipe
  (.+$)     # group 2, 1 or more any character until end of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]